# Creating a boolean to return true for Strings starting with a char and the proceeding values being either a char a digit or an underscore

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to create `Boolean` that returns `True` for strings consisting of
a letter followed by one or more letters, digits or underscore characters.

I get the following compile error:

"Couldn't match expected type  `Char -> Bool`
with actual type `Bool`
Possible cause: `or` is applied to too many arguments "

```
 isIdentifier :: String -> Bool
 isIdentifier [] = False
 isIdentifier (x:[]) = False
 isIdentifier(x:xs)
   | isAlpha x &&  length(filter(or [isAlpha, isDigit, (=='_')]) xs ) == length xs = True
   | otherwise = False
```

This is my code. I know from the error message that I need to somehow apply or to `xs` but I don't know how to do so without affecting the `filter` function.

I was wondering if there were better ways of setting up my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `or` is:

```
Prelude Data.Char> :t or
or :: Foldable t => t Bool -> Bool
```

It requires some `Foldable` container of `Bool` values, such as `[Bool]`, as input.

The input it receives, however, is a list of predicates:

```
Prelude Data.Char> :t [isAlpha, isDigit, (=='_')]
[isAlpha, isDigit, (=='_')] :: [Char -> Bool]
```

Notice that this expression has the type `[Char -> Bool]`. It doesn't fit the `or` function.

In order to pass an appropriate argument to the `filter` function, you'll need to find a way to turn `[Char -> Bool]` into `Char -> Bool`. Do you need help with that?

Comment: I think i'll give it a go myself but thank you for steering me towards the right direction

Answer (score 1):

After the considering @Mark Seemann guidance I decided to that i needed to create a function `isIdChar :: Char -> Bool` that tests if a `Char` fits the criteria of either being a letter , digit or underscore. I then used the function in my filter. That way the function returned `Char -> Bool` as @Mark Seemann suggested.

```
isIdChar :: Char -> Bool
isIdChar c = isAlpha c || isDigit c || c == '_'
isIdentifier :: String -> Bool
isIdentifier [] = False
isIdentifier (x:[]) = False
isIdentifier(x:xs)
   | isAlpha x &&  length(filter isIdChar xs ) == length xs = True
   | otherwise = False
```

Initially I used the `||` infix operator in my solution but I've also provided solution that uses the `or` function

```
isIdChar :: Char -> Bool
isIdChar c = or[isAlpha c, isDigit c , (c == '_')]
isIdentifier :: String -> Bool
isIdentifier [] = False
isIdentifier (x:[]) = False
isIdentifier(x:xs)
   | isAlpha x &&  length(filter isIdChar xs ) == length xs = True
   | otherwise = False
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a great place to use [the `swing` function](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree#Swing)! Just replace your `or` with `swing any`:

```
 swing :: (((a -> b) -> b) -> c -> d) -> c -> a -> d
 swing f c a = f ($ a) c

 isIdentifier :: String -> Bool
 isIdentifier [] = False
 isIdentifier (x:[]) = False
 isIdentifier(x:xs)
   | isAlpha x &&  length(filter(swing any [isAlpha, isDigit, (=='_')]) xs ) == length xs = True
   | otherwise = False
```

You can also simplify your function a bit:

```
swing :: (((a -> b) -> b) -> c -> d) -> c -> a -> d
swing f c a = f ($ a) c

isIdentifier :: String -> Bool
isIdentifier (x:xs@(_:_)) = isAlpha x && all (swing any [isAlpha, isDigit, (== '_')]) xs
isIdentifier _ = False
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to Haskell so please be patient with me what's the purpose of this bit of code `(x:xs@(_:_))`

Comment: @Peter It's like `(x:xs)`, but with the additional restriction that `xs` must be something `:` something else, rather than `[]` (in other words, it must be non-empty).